# Fluent UI React how to change nav link icon color?

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I want to change the nav link icon color. If I set the primary color by creating a custom theme it won't effect.

```
<ThemeProvider
  theme={{
    palette: {
      themePrimary: getTheme().palette.teal,
    }
  }}
>
```

Actually it worked on hover but not on normal view. I tried setting the `iconProps` but it didn't work either.

```
links: [
  {
    name: "Overview",
    icon: "WebAppBuilderFragment",
    iconProps: { color: "white" },
  },
],
```

How can I change these icons color?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IconProps` is an object with following [props](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/icon#IIconProps). Use `styles` to set icon color:

```js
links: [
  {
    name: "Overview",
    iconProps: {
      iconName: 'WebAppBuilderFragment',
      styles: {
        root: { color: '#f00' },
      },
    },
  },
],
```

[Codepen working](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/RwjvypV?editors=0010) example.